# What is wrong with my wp query? Trying to exclude category 14

Tags: wordpress

query('showposts='.$display_count.'&orderby=comment_count&category__not_in=14');

I do a standard query and it still wont leave out posts that are in category 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query('showposts='.$display_count.'&orderby=comment_count&cat=-14');
```